# Stop output when connecting to Exchange Online in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm currently building an Office 365 PowerShell application that connects to Exchange Online using:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
```

And while it works just fine, there is one small, insignificant, but annoying occurrence when connecting to a tenancy - the following output is displayed:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
We have released new management cmdlets which are faster and more reliable.

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Old Cmdlets                    |    New/Reliable/Faster Cmdlets       |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Get-CASMailbox                 |    Get-EXOCASMailbox                 |
|    Get-Mailbox                    |    Get-EXOMailbox                    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderPermission    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics    |
|    Get-MailboxPermission          |    Get-EXOMailboxPermission          |
|    Get-MailboxStatistics          |    Get-EXOMailboxStatistics          |
|    Get-MobileDeviceStatistics     |    Get-EXOMobileDeviceStatistics     |
|    Get-Recipient                  |    Get-EXORecipient                  |
|    Get-RecipientPermission        |    Get-EXORecipientPermission        |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|

To get additional information, run: Get-Help Connect-ExchangeOnline
Please send your feedback and suggestions to exocmdletpreview@service.microsoft.com
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's not a huge deal and has absolutely no effect on the functionality of my application.. it's just a bit of an eyesore and I'm a bit of a self confessed perfectionist! Is there any way to suppress this output? Casting to null doesn't seem to work and I'm not able to find anything anywhere else as to what may do the trick.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your module version, try to add the `-ShowBanner:$false` switch ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#version-043681)):

```bsh
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ShowBanner:$false
```

---

Another possibility might be to add `HideBannermessage=true` as a parameter to your URI ([source](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/5454#issuecomment-624162375)):

```bsh
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/?HideBannermessage=true"
```

Comment: The -ShowBanner:$false absolutely did the trick so thank you so much! And thank you for providing the source, I have looked at that document many a time and must of glazed over it - just wasn't aware of the concept of module banners..

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable if you dont want the output on the screen

```
$Connect=Connect-ExchangeOnline
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting!

This unfortunately did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use out null

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting!

As said in the post, casting to null doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Does the other answer help you or does it still output to the console?